how can i update a token logo on solscan for a project I work with?
I have ported a token from ethereum mainnet to solana using the wormhole portal bridge. How do i go about updating the token logo on solscan?

do you have the token update authority? you can use Tony's tools here
https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/token-tools/token-management

what do you mean by update authority? the original contract token is on mainnet ethereum and it is renounced. it was ported to solana using wormhole

How do mind dropping the address?

this is the wormhole port to solana contract address E8Cn4QEmZSvr55ZeAJwyo2r8kAX79qzdtQdFudDaZJCV
